# How can I replace my old list adapter with a new one on Android? It keeps appending new to old one

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I call a function createTheList that sends my layout, and array adapter. Then within the method I create my custom setListAdapter. Well, I want to change my list based on filters within my program. ie, if a person clicks a button, it shows a different list. So, I want to call the createTheList method again, and re-create the list while replacing my old list. I am having a real tough time figuring this out. If I call createTheList again with a different adapter, it just appends to the old list. Can anyone please walk me through this?

```
public void createTheList(final int num, String[] Array ){


      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layoutName, R.id.myText, Array){         

        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){



           final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           Button commentButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
           Button missingButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
           Button rideAlongButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button3);


            if (arrayOfShifts[position].getRideAlongCount()>0 && arrayOfShifts[position].positionOnList == position){
                rideAlongButton.setVisibility(row.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                rideAlongButton.setVisibility(row.GONE);
            }

            if (arrayOfShifts[position].getMissingCnt() > 0 && arrayOfShifts[position].positionOnList == position){
                missingButton.setVisibility(row.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                missingButton.setVisibility(row.GONE);
            }

            if (arrayOfShifts[position].getHasComment() > 0 && arrayOfShifts[position].positionOnList == position){
                commentButton.setVisibility(row.VISIBLE);
            }
            else{
                commentButton.setVisibility(row.GONE);
            }


            return row;

        }
     });
```

Where createTheList is being called from:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layoutName = R.layout.fragtest1;
    //My values to call a function
    cache.put("Value1", "02-12-2014");
    cache.put("Value2", 1);

    //getShifts method returns an array.
    String[] adapterArray = getShifts("GetShifts3" , cache);

    createTheList(layoutName, adapterArray);

    //If I add the following code, which is just a sample to replace my old list
    //instead of removing the old list, it appends to the old list.

    cache.clear();
    //New Data
    cache.put("Value1", "02-12-2014");
    cache.put("Value2", 2);

    String[] adapterArray2= getShifts("GetShifts3" , cache);

    createTheList(layoutName, adapterArray2);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the code where you call createTheList again?

Comment: ok I edited it. Its the snippet from the main java file. If you want I can send or post the whole file, but it is quiet large.

Comment: I call getShifts() method which returns me an array of data. I want to turn that data into a listview. So I use the createTheList() method, and create the custom setListAdapter, so based on the data I can create unique rows. For example show some buttons on some rows etc..

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetCHanged doesn't help?

Comment: nope, I tried doing various implementations of it. I am not sure if I am just doing it wrong, or it isn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the RemoveAll() or Clear() method of the List object.

Comment: I think that is one of the problems with my code. I don't know what my List Object is? I just randomly call setListAdapter, its not set to a variable or anything that I can modify..

Comment: Make the List strongly typed.  Do you have access to it?

Comment: what do you mean make it strongly typed? I believe I have access to it, yes.

Comment: I think I see your problem. If I understand your code correctly, you are passing adapterArray into the method and making changes to the list. However once the createTheList() completes its execution, all of its variables go out of scope.  In other words, it seems like you need to actually make the createTheList() return the new List and assign it. (i.e.   adapterArray = createTheList())  Does this help...?

Comment: Well I am not creating an adapterArray at all. I am calling the function and within the setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>....)
I think that is when I am creating the adapter. I think you are correct with the scope idea, I am going to try to have createTheList return an array Adapter. Once I do adapaterArray = createTheList(), then what do I do to replace my old list with a new list?

Comment: Moreover, I don't see where you are doing anything to the variable "Array" that is being passed in either.

Comment: Is variable "cache" the list you are trying to change or "adapterArray" ?

Comment: adapterArray is. cache is just a map object that I send to do some other work.

Comment: I just read some of your previous post. You are trying to convert the "String[] adapterArray2" into a listview. Thus:              public Listview createTheList(final int num, String[] Array ){ ///Whole bunch of code here                                      return aListView;  }       Then >>>>>>>> ListView thing = createTheList();

Comment: right now I have " public ArrayAdapter<String> createTheList(final int num, String[] Array ){...}" 

It returns the arrayAdapter, but now sure what to do with it.

Comment: Basically the flow goes like this: I get an array of data into "arrayAdapter". I send arrayAdapter to my createTheList method which has a setListAdapter that takes in "arrayAdapter" and creates a listview based on the contents. Later on in my program I want to have a filter option so that if they click a button, the list will be reduced. I figured for testing purposes, I can create a new array of data called "adapterArray2" and send that to createTheList() so that it will re-create a list and replace the old one.

Comment: It seems like you have a good plan of attack.  I would only suggest that you address the scoping issue. And then, declare a state variable in the Activity object to which to assign with the createTheList() method. That way you will always have access to modify ListView during the Activity existence. I hope this has been helpful...

Comment: thanks! you have definitely been helpful. I am still stuck and can't get "arrayAdapter2" to replace the old list. However I feel like I am really close...I think I am having problems with actually setting up my lists to variables and such. Its a mess lol >.<

Answer (score 0):

try to clear the String array variable "Array" before calling another list.

Comment: Won't allow me too. I tried to send a totally different array to the setListAdapter so that the contents will be new and fresh, but it didn't help.

Comment: can u provide a small screen shot of the output, i want to know how the next list is appended to the previous one.

Comment: well the lists are combined into one list. there is no distinction. I can't really post a screen shot.  But it goes like data1, data2, data3, differentdata1, differentdata2